# Forced Withdraw from L2 StarkEX

Tags: query

I need to request the forced withdraw function on the StarkEx smart contract in order to get my DYDX funds back to L1.
I have found an Github solidity code but no clue how to deploy it to StarkEx smart contract.

I have an open position on DYDX, can onboard to DYDX but just can`t close the position or place s stop loss order;
DYDX support / StarkEx support are not replying.

Can anyone help, please?

This is the Github-Code; just 56 lines but Im no coder...
https://github.com/starkware-libs/starkex-contracts/blob/ceb62c0cd127f9758f0a347f6bfbc9b5a8d0235f/scalable-dex/contracts/src/interactions/ForcedWithdrawals.sol#L17

Answer (score 0):

dydx.l2beat.com

use the above site its user friendly its been long since you posted but i guess you still may need it for future